# Discord Won't Launch 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Discord and it refuses to load. If I switch over to the discord window, it shows a blank screen with no error messages attached to it.

I've tried reinstalling the program and that didn't fix it. I also cleared my config folder after a Discord staff member tried to help me and never replied back with an alternative solution.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. And I'm running the latest version of Discord which is 0.0.1.

Comment: How did you install it? What were the commands used?

Comment: I downloaded the file off the official Discord site. It was a .deb file.

Comment: Can you download the .deb file again and install it using `dpkg`?

Comment: I downloaded the file again. Then I removed discord and installed it once again via dpkg. It still boots to a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error when I execute the program w/o terminal. 
However, when you run the command `discord` in terminal (or simply use the online version), it works fine. There may be a few errors with the mic, but you can fix the settings. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on XUbuntu 16.04 using the gzip package (Discord 0.0.4). Installed "libc++1" package and Discord launched successfully--no more empty window:

```
sudo aptitude install libc++1
```

Note: I found forum posts which indicated "libc++" was required and to install clang toolchain package which should include libc++.  This did not work so I suspect newer version of Discord requires newer libc++ provided by libc++**1**